# Printing ZPL strings in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, barcode, zpl

Does anyone know how can I print ZPL strings in Silverlight? So from a web request, I get a response of string that should be printed in a label printer (e.g. Zebra printer). So printing should be done in the client, I cannot use the raw data printing provided [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091)
because Silverlight cannot access some type or namespace like ManagementClass.

If anyone knows some solution, I would be glad to hear it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Setup a new driver using the Generic Text driver:

Start > Devices and Printers > Add Printer > Add Local Printer > Choose or create the correct port > Select Generic from the manufacturer list and Generic / Text only from the Printers list

Assuming the Silverlight program can print to the driver, it should pass the ZPL straight through.